# regex to reorder text with MS Word 2010 or Notepad++

Tags: regex, ms-word, notepad++

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a long document, styles as a dictionary.

I have this:

```
÷H1.
John.
walks,
drives,
eats,
drinks,
flies,
travels,

÷H2.
Peter.
flies,
rides,
swims,

÷H3.
James.
laughs,
cries,
```

I need it like this:

```
÷H1. John. walks,
÷H1. John. drives,
÷H1. John. eats,
÷H1. John. drinks,
÷H1. John. flies,
÷H1. John. travels,

÷H2. Peter. flies,
÷H2. Peter. rides,
÷H2. Peter. swims,

÷H3. James. laughs,
÷H3. James. cries,
```

Thank you!
Alex

Comment: ooh! So which would be the easiest program to use, for someone inexperienced like me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps in notepad++ with regular expressions checked:

1. Find: `(÷[^.]+\.)[\r\n]+([^.]+\.)`

   Replace: `$1 $2`
2. Find: `(÷[^\r\n]+.)[\r\n]{1,2}([a-z]+,)`

   Replace: `$1 $2`
3. Find: `((÷[^\r\n,]+\.)[^\r\n]+[\r\n]{1,2})([a-z])`

   Replace: `$1$2 $3`

Repeat step 3 as many times as necessary.

Comment: @user2792945 You're welcome! Let me know if you have any issues :)

Comment: @user2792945 Awesome then! Could you please click the tick outline next to my answer to accept it? :)

Comment: Jerry, I appreciate your answer, it helped open my eyes to more ideas! :)

Comment: Jerry, I give up trying on my own! I just could not figure it out.

Comment: @user2792945 Don't worry, it took me a few tries to get the set of steps above ^^;

Comment: Hi Jerry, please have a look at it for me. It's basically the same as this one you figured out, except I don't have the periods and the commas at the end of each line. I just don't know enough regex to manipulate text. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890244/notepad-regex-reorder-text-a-bit-more-complex
Thanks buddy :)

Comment: @user2792945 I'll try to see if I can do something. ^^