# Notepad++ regex reorder text a bit more complex

Tags: regex, excel, notepad++

In trying to simplify, I had originally asked this question and I got an answer that works correctly here: [regex to reorder text with MS Word 2010 or Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880876/regex-to-reorder-text-with-ms-word-2010-or-notepad)

Unfortunately I tried to then apply what I learned but I could not figure it out!

It's a lexicon, so for each entry (÷H1, ÷H2, ÷H3, etc etc etc) there are 1 or more "KJV Occurrences".
IE: "÷H1" only has 1 word: "***abidan***".
But, "÷H2" has 2 words "***abida***" and "***abidah***".
and, "÷H3" has 3 words "***abijah***", "***abiah***" and "***abia***".

(some entries have as many as 100 words! And I need to account for them as shown at the bottom, as tab delimited so I can then open the text file with MS Excel).

This is how I have it:

÷H1
אֲבִידָן
’ăbı̂ydânn
BDB Definition:
Abidan = “my father is judge”
1) a prince (ruler) of Benjamin
Part of Speech: noun proper masculine
A Related Word by BDB/Strong’s Number: from H1 and H1777
Total KJV Occurrences: 5
***abidan***, 5
Num_1:11, Num_2:22, Num_7:60, Num_7:65, Num_10:24

÷H2
אֲבִידָע
’ăbı̂ydâ‛
BDB Definition:
Abida or Abidah = “my father knows”
1) fourth son of Midian and grandson of Abraham by his wife Keturah (after Sarah died)
Part of Speech: noun proper masculine
A Related Word by BDB/Strong’s Number: from H1 and H3045
Total KJV Occurrences: 2
***abida***, 1
1Ch_1:33
***abidah***, 1
Gen_25:4

÷H3
אֲבִיָּהוּ  /  אֲבִיָּה
’ăbı̂yâh  /  ’ăbı̂yâhû
BDB Definition:
Abia or Abiah or Abijah = “Jehovah is (my) father”
1) king of Judah, son and successor of Rehoboam
2) second son of Samuel
3) son of Jeroboam the first, king of Israel
4) son of Becher, a Benjamite
5) head of a priestly house (one of the 24 Levite groups)
6) head of a priestly house (after the exile)
7) wife of Hezron
8) mother of Hezekiah (compare H21)
Part of Speech: noun proper masculine
A Related Word by BDB/Strong’s Number: from H1 and H3050
Total KJV Occurrences: 25
***abijah***, 20
1Ki_14:1, 1Ch_24:10, 2Ch_11:20, 2Ch_11:22, 2Ch_12:16, 2Ch_13:1-4 (4), 2Ch_13:15, 2Ch_13:17, 2Ch_13:19-22 (4), 2Ch_29:1 (2), Neh_10:7, Neh_12:4, Neh_12:17
***abiah***, 4
1Sa_8:2, 1Ch_2:24, 1Ch_6:28, 1Ch_7:8
***abia***, 1
1Ch_3:10

---

This is how I need it:

÷H1 TABDELIMITED    אֲבִידָן    TABDELIMITED    ’ăbı̂ydân TABDELIMITED    BDB Definition: Abidan = “my father is judge”. 1) a prince (ruler) of Benjamin. TABDELIMITED    Part of Speech: noun proper masculine.  TABDELIMITED    A Related Word by BDB/Strong’s Number: from H1 and H1777.   TABDELIMITED    Total KJV Occurrences: 5    TABDELIMITED    ***abidan***    TABDELIMITED    , 5 TABDELIMITED    Num_1:11, Num_2:22, Num_7:60, Num_7:65, Num_10:24

÷H2 TABDELIMITED    אֲבִידָע    TABDELIMITED    ’ăbı̂ydâ‛ TABDELIMITED    BDB Definition: Abida or Abidah = “my father knows”. 1) fourth son of Midian and grandson of Abraham by his wife Keturah (after Sarah died).    TABDELIMITED    Part of Speech: noun proper masculine.  TABDELIMITED    A Related Word by BDB/Strong’s Number: from H1 and H3045.   TABDELIMITED    Total KJV Occurrences: 2    TABDELIMITED    ***abida*** TABDELIMITED    , 1 TABDELIMITED    1Ch_1:33

÷H2 TABDELIMITED    אֲבִידָע    TABDELIMITED    ’ăbı̂ydâ‛ TABDELIMITED    BDB Definition: Abida or Abidah = “my father knows”. 1) fourth son of Midian and grandson of Abraham by his wife Keturah (after Sarah died).    TABDELIMITED    Part of Speech: noun proper masculine.  TABDELIMITED    A Related Word by BDB/Strong’s Number: from H1 and H3045.   TABDELIMITED    Total KJV Occurrences: 2    TABDELIMITED    ***abidah***    TABDELIMITED    , 1 TABDELIMITED    Gen_25:4

÷H3 TABDELIMITED    אֲבִיָּהוּ  /  אֲבִיָּה TABDELIMITED    ’ăbı̂yâh  /  ’ăbı̂yâhû TABDELIMITED    BDB Definition: Abia or Abiah or Abijah = “Jehovah is (my) father”. 1) king of Judah, son and successor of Rehoboam. 2) second son of Samuel. 3) son of Jeroboam the first, king of Israel. 4) son of Becher, a Benjamite. 5) head of a priestly house (one of the 24 Levite groups). 6) head of a priestly house (after the exile). 7) wife of Hezron. 8) mother of Hezekiah (compare H21).    TABDELIMITED    Part of Speech: noun proper masculine.  TABDELIMITED    A Related Word by BDB/Strong’s Number: from H1 and H3050.   TABDELIMITED    Total KJV Occurrences: 25   TABDELIMITED    ***abijah***    TABDELIMITED    , 20    TABDELIMITED    1Ki_14:1, 1Ch_24:10, 2Ch_11:20, 2Ch_11:22, 2Ch_12:16, 2Ch_13:1-4 (4), 2Ch_13:15, 2Ch_13:17, 2Ch_13:19-22 (4), 2Ch_29:1 (2), Neh_10:7, Neh_12:4, Neh_12:17

÷H3 TABDELIMITED    אֲבִיָּהוּ  /  אֲבִיָּה TABDELIMITED    ’ăbı̂yâh  /  ’ăbı̂yâhû TABDELIMITED    BDB Definition: Abia or Abiah or Abijah = “Jehovah is (my) father”. 1) king of Judah, son and successor of Rehoboam. 2) second son of Samuel. 3) son of Jeroboam the first, king of Israel. 4) son of Becher, a Benjamite. 5) head of a priestly house (one of the 24 Levite groups). 6) head of a priestly house (after the exile). 7) wife of Hezron. 8) mother of Hezekiah (compare H21).    TABDELIMITED    Part of Speech: noun proper masculine.  TABDELIMITED    A Related Word by BDB/Strong’s Number: from H1 and H3050.   TABDELIMITED    Total KJV Occurrences: 25   TABDELIMITED    ***abiah*** TABDELIMITED    , 4 TABDELIMITED    1Sa_8:2, 1Ch_2:24, 1Ch_6:28, 1Ch_7:8

÷H3 TABDELIMITED    אֲבִיָּהוּ  /  אֲבִיָּה TABDELIMITED    ’ăbı̂yâh  /  ’ăbı̂yâhû TABDELIMITED    BDB Definition: Abia or Abiah or Abijah = “Jehovah is (my) father”. 1) king of Judah, son and successor of Rehoboam. 2) second son of Samuel. 3) son of Jeroboam the first, king of Israel. 4) son of Becher, a Benjamite. 5) head of a priestly house (one of the 24 Levite groups). 6) head of a priestly house (after the exile). 7) wife of Hezron. 8) mother of Hezekiah (compare H21).    TABDELIMITED    Part of Speech: noun proper masculine.  TABDELIMITED    A Related Word by BDB/Strong’s Number: from H1 and H3050.   TABDELIMITED    Total KJV Occurrences: 25   TABDELIMITED    ***abia***  TABDELIMITED    , 1 TABDELIMITED    1Ch_3:10

I need to have it tab delimited so I can then open it with MS Excel, with a row for each one or more ÷H1's ÷H2's ÷H3's ... where all the words I emphasized in bold/italic will eventually fall into column H of my Excel spreadsheet.

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: I think you are asking too much of Notepad++, not because Notepad++ cannot do it but because the REs will be big and complicated. If you need to repeat the procedure on another file, or do it slightly differently then you would have to enter the REs in again. Better, I believe, to write a script in something like Awk or Perl or Python, or even in Excel's scripting language.

Comment: Hi AdrianHHH, I'm not a programmer and I already have the answer in Notepad++, except I cannot figure out how to apply it. Here's the answer. Do you know how to do it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880876/regex-to-reorder-text-with-ms-word-2010-or-notepad

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about says "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers", it is not a place to get your work done for free. As you state that the answer is already given in another question, what have you tried for this question, with what effect and why is it different to what you want?

Comment: AdrianHHH, this works perfectly to create the first 3 records, the problem is I don't know how to modify it to put tabs after each, so I can end up with all the bold/italic words in the same H column when opening in Excel.

Steps in notepad++ with regular expressions checked:

Find: (÷[^.]+\.)[\r\n]+([^.]+\.)

Replace: $1 $2

Find: (÷[^\r\n]+.)[\r\n]{1,2}([a-z]+,)

Replace: $1 $2

Find: ((÷[^\r\n,]+\.)[^\r\n]+[\r\n]{1,2})([a-z])

Replace: $1$2 $3

Repeat step 3 as many times as necessary.

Please shed some light :) I appreciate it.

Comment: There is a RegExp for *one* "KJV Occurrences". FIND: `^(÷[^ ]+)( )([^ ]+( \/ [^ ]+)?)( )([^ ]+( \/ [^ ]+)?)( )(.*)( )(Part of Speech:.*)( )(A Related Word by BDB/Strong’s Number:.*)( )(Total KJV Occurrences: \d+)( )(.*)(, \d+)( )(.*)` REPLACE: `$1\t$3\t$6\t$9.\t$11.\t$13.\t$15\t$17\t$18\t$20` If you want handle more occurances you should write a script as @AdrianHHH said. But maybe some NPP plugin can help you (NppExec, Python etc.) +1 hint: try regexhero.net/tester. I hope it helps.

Comment: To add a tab character put the two characters `\t` into the replacement text. To understand the full facilities of the Notepad++ regular expressions, see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html

Comment: Stocki, thank you for you help. Which version are you using? I'm trying the FIND: ^(÷[^ ]+)( )([^ ]+( \/ [^ ]+)?)( )([^ ]+( \/ [^ ]+)?)( )(.*)( )(Part of Speech:.*)( )(A Related Word by BDB/Strong’s Number:.*)( )(Total KJV Occurrences: \d+)( )(.*)(, \d+)( )(.*)
in Notepad++ v6.4.5 Unicode, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, this one is much more complex than your previous question... I will use `<space>` to indicate a space character and not the literal "space" word.

Steps:

1. Find: `(Definition:)[\r\n]{1,2}|[\r\n]{1,2}(?=\d+\))`

   Replace by: `<space>`

   This part should bring all the definitions in a single line.
2. Find:

   ```
   (÷[^\r\n]+)[\r\n]{1,2}([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]{1,2}([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]{1,2}([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]{1,2}([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]{1,2}([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]{1,2}([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]{1,2}([^\r\n,]+),([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]{1,2}([^\r\n]+)
   ```

   Replace by: `$1\t$2\t$3\t$4\t$5\t$6\t$7\t$8\t$9\t$10`
3. Find:

   ```
   ((÷(?![^\r\n]+[\r\n]{1,2}÷)(?:[^\t]+\t){7})[^\r\n]+[\r\n]{1,2})([^\r\n,]+),([^\r\n]+)[\r\n]{1,2}([^\r\n]+)
   ```

   Replace by: `$1$2$3\t$4\t$5`

And repeat step 3 as many times as necessary.

**EDIT:** If you just want `÷H1` followed by the bold words, you could try:

1. Find: `^(÷[^\r\n]+)[\s\S]+?Total KJV Occurrences: \d+`

   Replace by: `$1`
2. Find: `(÷[^\r\n]+)[\r\n]{1,2}([^,]+),[^\r\n]+[\r\n]{1,2}[^\r\n]+`

   Replace by: `$1\t$2`
3. Find

   ```
   ((÷[^\s]+)[^\r\n]+[\r\n]{1,2}(?![\r\n]*÷))([^,]+),[^\r\n]+[\r\n]{1,2}[^\r\n]+
   ```

   Replace by: `$1$2\t$3`

And repeat step 3 as many times as necessary.

Comment: Hi Jerry, I'm trying it but it's not doing the intended thing. I believe you misunderstood my intent: I'm not worried about everything between "÷Hxxxx" and "Total KJV Occurrences: xxxx". It's right after "Total KJV Occurrences: xxxx" that I need to gather each "Occurrence" and tag it with the appropriate ÷Hxxx where it comes from. In other words, I'd be happy to just extract a list such as:

÷H1 TAB "abidan"
÷H2 TAB "abida"
÷H2 TAB "abidah"
÷H3 TAB "abijah"
÷H3 TAB "abiah"
÷H3 TAB "abia"

just the words that I made bold/italic in my sample text.

Comment: @user2792945 Oh, okay, I guess I can try that tomorrow (in about 10 hours) It's late where I am :( Though I'm not sure why it isn't working. When I put the results in an excel, all the bold words get into column H. Oh well, I'll try something tomorrow.

Comment: Good morning Jerry! You were right, it works fine as you said and they all line up nicely in column H. But when running it on the whole big Hebrew lexicon file.. ÷H1 to ÷H8674 you know how it is... :) there was other stuff to consider, and yet other+other+other stuff to clean-up. So... I'm throwing a mini-party here at home and thanking Abba for intelligent/friendly people like you! This was a breakthrough because now I have to do the same for the new testament lexicon, which will be a breeze, thanks to you! Thanks so much Jerry, I'll keep you updated on my progress. :) Alex

Comment: @Alex Okay, I've put the version you spoke about in your first comment in the answer. This gives you only the chapter (I think that's the chapter) and the keywords you put in bold after a tab character.

Comment: oh yeah, never mind! I did do little tweaks but all based on how you helped me understand how it work :) Thanks so much, Jerry!